# Pylint disagrees with VSCode and python in imports

Tags: python, pylint

I am not finding the way to properly code so that both pylint **and** the execution of the code (within VSCode or from the command line) would work.

There are some similar questions but none seems to apply to my project structure with a src directory under which there will be multiple packages. Here's the simplified project structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── rssita
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── feeds.py
│   │   ├── rssita.py
│   │   └── termcolors.py
│   └── zanotherpackage
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── anothermodule.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_feeds.py
```

From what I understand **rssita** is one of my my packages (because of the **init**.py file) with some modules under it amongst which **rssita.py** file contains the following imports:

```
from feeds import RSS_FEEDS
from termcolors import PC
```

The **rssita.py** code as shown above runs well from both within **VSCode** and from command line **python** ( python src/rssita/rssita.py ) from the project root, but at the same time **pylint** (both from within VSCode and from the command line (*pylint src* or *pylint src/rssita*)) flags the two imports as not found.

If I modify the code as follows:

```
from rssita.feeds import RSS_FEEDS
from rssita.termcolors import PC
```

pylint will then be happy but the code will not run anymore since it would not find the imports.

What's the cleanest fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned pylinty is right, your setup / PYTHONPATH is screwed up: in Python 3, all imports are absolute by default, so

```py
from feeds import RSS_FEEDS
from termcolors import PC
```

should look for top-level packages called `feeds` and `termcolors` which I don't think exist.

> `python src/rssita/rssita.py`

That really ain't the correct invocation, it's going to setup a really weird PYTHONPATH in order to run a random script.

The correct imports should be [package-relative](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports):

```py
from .feeds import RSS_FEEDS
from .termcolors import PC
```

Furthermore if you intend to run a package, that should be either [a runnable package using `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#main-py-in-python-packages):

```
python -m rssita
```

or you should run the sub-package as a module:

```
python -m rssita.rssita
```

Because you're using an src-package, you'll either need to create a `pyproject.toml` so you can use an editable install, or you'll have to `PYTHONPATH=src` before you run the command. This ensures the packages are visible at the top-level of the PYTHONPATH, and thus correctly importable. Though I'm not a specialist in the interaction of src layouts & runnable packages, so there may be better solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear. poetry manages my env and created the pyproject.toml file for it with a "packages = [{include = "rssita", from = "src"}]" line ...

Comment: Using package-relative imports soothes pylint :) but "from .feeds import RSS_FEEDS
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"